# how to find URL of some elements of a webpage?

Tags: python, selenium

the webpage is : https://www.vpgame.com/market/gold?order_type=pro_price&order=desc&offset=0

As you can see there are 25 items in the selling part of this page that when you click them it opens a new tab and show you that specific item details.
Now I want to make a program to get those 25 item URLs and save them in a list, and my problem is as you can see in page inspect, their tags are  which should be  and also I can't find any 'href' attributes that related to them.

```
# using selenium and driver = webdriver.Chrome()
link = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
link2 = [l.get_attribute('href') for l in link]
```

I thought I can do it with above code but the problem is what I said. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to scrape a page that is powered by react. There are no `href` tags because javascript is powering all the linking. Your best bet is to use selenium to execute a click on each of the `div` objects, switch to the newly tabe, and use something like this code to get the URL of the page it's taken you to:

```
import time
links = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-header')
urls = []
for link in links: 
    new_page = link.click()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    url = driver.current_url
    urls.append(url)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Note that the code closes the new tab each time and goes back to the main tab. I added `time.sleep()` so it doesn't go too fast.

Comment: yes it works, thank you , but isn't there any faster ways to do so?